# Why is a strange character appearing on my screen?

Tags: c

I am new to C, I have written a very simple program to get the first name and surname, here is my code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    int num,bankpin;
    char fn[20],sn[20];
    
    printf("Welcome to authorization. We ill now begin the process");
    printf("\nFirst, please enter your first name: ");
    scanf(" %s",fn);
    printf("\nEnter your surname: ");
    scanf(" %s",sn);
    printf("\nWelcome to the system %c %c",&fn,&sn);
    return 0;
}
```

```
Welcome to authorization. We ill now begin the process
First, please enter your first name: A

Enter your surname: A

Welcome to the system   α
```

Why is this strange "a" appearing on my screen instead of "A A"?

In fact it appears on my screen even if I try a different combination of letters

I have even tried recompiling the code

Comment: Use `"%s"` to print a **string**; `"%c"` is used to print **one** character.

Comment: To answer your question: you invoked **undefined behaviour** by passing the address of an array to printf with an associated `"%c"`.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings! You should've got a warning there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is because you are trying to print `&fn`, which is a pointer, as char. You're basically telling the program to interpret the address o as a symbol code.
Try changing the
`printf("\nWelcome to the system %c %c",&fn,&sn)` to
`printf("\nWelcome to the system %s %s",fn,sn)`

Comment: This is wrong too. Just `%s` and `fn`.

Comment: Note: you should pass not pass the addres of the array, but the address of the first element --> `printf("Welcome to the system %s %s\n", fn, sn);` [also, prefer to finish the prints with `"\n"` rather than starting like that]

Comment: Yes, I realized that just now. I was focused on the `%c`.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

You are sending the array pointer's address as an argument, and telling printf to interpret it as a single char, resulting in undefined behavior. The fix is to replace the line

```
printf("\nWelcome to the system %c %c",&fn,&sn);
```

with

```
printf("\nWelcome to the system %s %s",fn,sn);
```

### Long answer

The weird character is due to your code reading an unintended value, and trying to interpret it. If you run your code a few times, you will find that you don't always get this symbol, but many other ones, including nothing at all (seemingly). What is going here ?

The short answer is that you are misinforming the printf function by giving her a false symbol and a false value. Let's look at a similar example :

```
char myString[20] = "Hello!";
printf("%c", &myString);
```

In this snippet we create an array of characters, which actually means creating a pointer of char* type, and allocating its size (here to 20). Pointers are often confusing when starting with C, but they are in principle pretty simple : they are simply variables that, instead of containing a value, contain an address. Since arrays in C store their value sequentially, that is one after the other, it makes quite a lot of sense to have them be pointers : if you know where the array starts, and that its members are spaced evenly, it makes it quite easy to go over the array.

So since your array is a pointer, reading it directly will print something along the lines of "0x7ffc5a6dbb70". Putting '&' before it gives a very similar result : this operator consists in asking for the address of a variable, which is then in your code transmitted to the printf as an argument.

This doesn't make any sense there : a char is, in C, behind the scene, actually an integer variable with very small capacity, from 0 to 255 to be precise. For example the two lines in the following snippet produce the same result :

```
printf("%c", 'a');
printf("%c", 97);
```

Now you see what is happening in the original printf : the function is expecting to receive a very small integer to convert to one character, and instead receives an address, which is the reason why the output is so weird. Since addresses change basically at every run of the code, that is also the reason why the output changes very often.

You thus need to adapt the information in the printf function. First, inform that you wish to print a char array with the symbol "%s". This will make the function expect to receive a pointer to the first element of a char array, which it will then iterate over. Thus, as argument, you need to send this pointer, that you directly have in the form of the myString variable.

Thus running

```
char myString[20] = "Hello!";
printf("%s", myString);
```

prints 'Hello!', as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

The funcion `scanf` is a little tricky, please delete the leading space, inside quotes only include what are you expecting to receive, ever.

```c
scanf("%s",fn);
```

The `printf` function needs %s, same as `scanf`, to deal with string, later you don't need the & operator in this case.

```c
printf("\nWelcome to the system %s %s",fn,sn);
```